# Getting Error when running Robotframework tests in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

In Eclipse (RIDE) am using the below configuration and running the tests. When running in console I am not getting any errors.

Robot Framework version     3.2.1
Python version              3.8.5
chrome browser version      85.0.4183.83
chrome Web driver version   85.0.4183.83

**But when I am running in Jenkins I am getting the follow error.**
16:04:03.021    INFO    Opening browser 'chrome' to base url 'https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/'.
16:04:06.430    FAIL    **SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81**

Can someone help on this?

Comment: It seems to be pretty clear, the Chrome driver on the Jenkins host machine does not match the browser.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. How to get the issue resolved in Jenkins?

Comment: Well, you should update the chromedriver on the Jenkins machine somehow.